# Can I retrieve SharePoint 2010 workflow steps with PowerShell

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I can use powershell to get the names of all SharePoint Designer workflows in my farm - but is there a way to look at the steps of the workflow?

Specifically, this farm has the `iLoveSharePoint.Workflow.Activities` solution installed and I want to find all workflows that utilize any of those custom activities.

(I have another farm that uses Virto custom workflow activities too and will need similar info on it later)

This is for SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

You can download xoml file. 
It contains information about all activities.
Example (without parsing for list activities):

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Function GetXOMLFromWorkflowInstance($wfa)
{
    [xml]$xmldocument =  $wfa.SoapXml
    $name = $xmldocument.FirstChild.GetAttribute("Name")
    $wfName = $name.Replace(" ", "%20")
    $webRelativeFolder = "Workflows/" + $wfName
    $xomlFileName = $wfName + ".xoml"

    $wfFolder = $wfa.ParentWeb.GetFolder($webRelativeFolder)

    $xomlFile = $wfFolder.Files[$xomlFileName]
    if ($xomlFile.Exists)
    {
        $xomlStream = $xomlFile.OpenBinaryStream()
        $xmldocument.Load($xomlStream)
        $xomlStream.Close()

        return $xmldocument.OuterXml
    }

    return $xomlFileName
}

Function LoadAllWFXoml ($webUrl, $listName)
{
    $site = Get-SPSite($webUrl)
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()
    $wfaColl = $web.GetList($listName).WorkflowAssociations

    Foreach ($i in $wfaColl)
    {
        $xml = GetXOMLFromWorkflowInstance $i
        Write-Host $xml
        Write-Host "=============================="
    }
}

LoadAllWFXoml "http://site_url" "Lists/MyList"
```